# How to disconnect FireBase sockets?

Tags: node.js, sockets, firebase, nest

I am using firebase in NodeJs for getting motion detection events from Nest Camera.

I am connecting using the following code as I need multiple socket connections for each nest user.

```
this.context = new Firebase.Context();
this.firebaseClient = new Firebase(config.nest.firebaseSocketUrl, this.context);
```

I want to disconnect a particular socket whenever a user changes its mode to standby or home.

As per firebase documentation, you can use `Firebase.goOffline()` which is not useful in my case. How can I disconnect a specific firebase socket?

Comment: Why is `goOffline()` not useful? I do not fully understand why you want to disconnect the socket.

Comment: @PierreC. I want to disconnect it because I don't need it when user's system is in home or standby mode. I want to reduce load on our server when socket is not needed I wanted to disconnect it. Each of our user is connected to there Nest Account, for each user there's separate socket at our back end server. If 10,000 users have connected there nest account with our system then we need to maintain 10,000 socket connections which is not a good solution off course.

Comment: @PierreC. goOffline() is used to disconnect all of the sockets but I need to disconnect specific socket depending upon user who has changed its mode from away to home or standby. As you can see in my code I have used new Firebase.Context() as second parameter, that's used for making separate connection for each user.

Comment: I don't know much about the Context thing. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Engineer here,

I've answered a similar question regarding how Nest and Firebase interact [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013607/how-can-i-subscribe-to-many-nest-devices-from-many-different-users-using-a-singl/31087162#31087162), but I'll provide a little more color on how you can get data from multiple Nest devices on a single client.

In short, Nest stores data in a structure that looks like:

```
users
  $userID
    devices
      $deviceID
        // info about devices
```

When you call `authWithCustomToken()`, you're taken down to the appropriate `$userID`, and can subscribe to changes on those users' devices. This means you can't really access data across multiple users' devices since by authenticating you "move down the tree" to that user data. There's no way to move up (typically you could call `parent()`, but this doesn't work in Nest Firebase land).

Since a Firebase realtime database connection takes a single auth token per conncetion, you would have to `auth()` and `unauth()` multiple times to do this (going offline and online doesn't really do it, as we'll continue to use the same connection), and I *highly* suggest you avoid doing this, as it won't scale well.

Instead, you should use the [streaming REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-streaming), which allows you to create streaming REST connections, each authenticated with the user token. You can also control when these connections are open/closed. It's a little more work to manage, but if you're aiming for granular control, this is the level of control you're looking for. Some examples are [here](https://github.com/firebase/EventSource-Examples).

We're working with Nest to create a better experience here, but for now this is what we both recommend.

Comment: If i don't need to disconnect socket connection then is it better to use sockets instead of REST APIs?  Does REST API solution scale better then sockets? How many socket connections are allowed by firebase to connect with at a time? How many Rest API connections can be made at time? Are there any limit on number of opened connections or not?

Comment: If you don't need to authenticate multiple users on a single process (either unauthenticated or single user), you're fine using our Node client. If you need to authenticate multiple users, you either need to create a single process per authenticated user or use REST, which just takes an `?auth=<JWT>` query parameter. Socket connections and REST connections will likely be limitations on your side rather than ours, as we handle millions of open sockets at any given time.